# Inequality regarding Matrix Norm and Inverse Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces, self-learning

Currently, I'm stuck to one of a statement in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08560). Following is a brief summary of the paper regarding my question. (although the topic of the paper is mainly statistics, the question purely relies on mathematics)

> For $\lambda>0,\beta\in\mathbb R^p,n<p,X\in\mathbb R^{n\times p} ,\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{p\times p}$,  let $B_{X,\Sigma} := \lambda^2\beta^T(S_X+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma(S_X+\lambda I)^{-1}\beta$ where $S_X= X^TX/n$. Under these facts, show the following inequality, where $C_1,C_2>0$ are constants:
> $$\begin{aligned}
> |B_{X_1,\Sigma_1}- B_{X_2,\Sigma_2}| &\le C_1\Vert S_{X_1}-S_{X_2}\Vert_{op} + C_2\Vert\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2 \Vert_{op} \\
> &\le \frac{C_1}{n}(\Vert X_1\Vert_{op}  + \Vert X_2\Vert_{op} )\cdot\Vert X_1-X_2\Vert_{op} +  C_2\Vert\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2 \Vert_{op} 
> \end{aligned}$$

The second inequality is straightforward by "adding and subtracting" some terms $X_1^TX_2$ and applying $\Vert A+B\Vert_{op} \le  \Vert A \Vert_{op} +\Vert B \Vert_{op}$ and $\Vert AB \Vert_{op} \le \Vert A \Vert_{op}\Vert B \Vert_{op}$.

The thing is the first inequality. I tried to "add and subtract" several term between $B_{X_1,\Sigma_1}$ and $B_{X_2,\Sigma_2}$ such as $\lambda^2\beta^T(S_{X_1}+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma_2(S_{X_1}+\lambda I)^{-1}\beta$, but I'm not sure whether this kind of approach is correct and if so, how I can proceed from here. Especially, I need to extract the terms $S_{X_1}-S_{X_2}$ and $\Sigma_1-\Sigma_2$, but this isn't simple because of the inverse term $(S_X+\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify notation, you are trying to bound an expression of the form
$$
\lambda^2\big|\beta^TA_1^{-1}F_1A_1^{-1}\beta-\beta^TA_2^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}\beta\big|,
$$

where $F_j=\Sigma_j$ and $A_j=S_{X_j}+\lambda I$.

Note that $(S_{X_j}+\lambda I)\geq\lambda I$, so $\|(S_{X_j}+\lambda I)^{-1}\|\leq\lambda^{-1}$ and so $\|A_j^{-1}\beta\|\leq\lambda^{-1}\,\|\beta\|$. Also $\|\beta^T A_j^{-1}\|\leq\lambda^{-1}\,\|\beta\|$, $\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$ and
\begin{align}
\|A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1}\|&=\|A_2^{-1}(A_2-A_1)A_1^{-1}\|\leq\|A_2^{-1}\|\,\|A_1^{-1}\|\,\|A_2-A_1\|\abajo
&\leq\lambda^{-2}\,\|A_2-A_1\|.
\end{align}

Let $L=\big\|A_1^{-1}F_1A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|$. You have
\begin{align}
L
&\leq\big\|A_1^{-1}F_1A_1^{-1}-A_1^{-1}F_1A_2^{-1}\big\|
+\big\|A_1^{-1}F_1A_2^{-1}-A_1^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|\abajo
&\qquad\qquad+\big\|A_1^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}-A_2^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|\abajo
&=\big\|(A_1^{-1}F_1)(A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1})\big\|
+\big\|A_1^{-1}(F_1-F_2)A_2^{-1}\big|+\big\|(A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1})F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|\abajo
&\leq\big\|A_1^{-1}F_1\|\,\|A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1}\big\|
+\lambda^{-2}\big\|F_1-F_2\big\|+\lambda^{-2}\big\|F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|\,\|A_2-A_1\|\abajo
&\leq \lambda^{-3}(\|F_1\|+\|F_2\|)\,\|A_2-A_1\|+\lambda^{-2}\,\|F_2-F_1\|.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
|B_{X_1,\Sigma_1}- B_{X_2,\Sigma_2}|
&=\lambda^2\big|\beta^T(A_1^{-1}F_1A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1})\beta\big|\abajo
&\leq\lambda^2\|\beta\|^2\,\big\|A_1^{-1}F_1A_1^{-1}-A_2^{-1}F_2A_2^{-1}\big\|\abajo
&\leq\lambda^{-1}\|\beta\|^2(\|F_1\|+\|F_2\|)\,\|A_2-A_1\|+\|\beta\|^2\,\|F_2-F_1\|.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, I got it. thank you for your explanation.

Comment: BTW, what does the typo \abajo in the above inequality mean? I just disregarded it at the first time (because it still makes sence in my understanding).

Comment: It's a macro that got in front of its definition. It's corrected now. Also, please upvote if you found the answer useful.